# `connection refused` to a local container while running doing`docker-compose build app`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a Rails application in containers and I would like to use a service like `geminabox` or `gemstash` to proxy https://rubygems.org et have a faster `bundle install` command.

I have started a gemstash container publishing the port 9292 and with `curl` on my host I can reach the service.

In the `Dockerfile` of my Rails application I have added the following line, before the `bundle install`:

```
RUN bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org http://localhost:9292
```

When I run `docker-compose build app` (`app` is the service name) I have bundler failing with the following:

```
Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9292
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:88:in `block in timeout'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `call'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:98:in `timeout'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:858:in `start'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:702:in `start'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:633:in `connection_for'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendored_persistent.rb:23:in `connection_for'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/net-http-persistent/lib/net/http/persistent.rb:996:in `request'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/downloader.rb:51:in `request'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/downloader.rb:17:in `fetch'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/fetcher/compact_index.rb:117:in `call'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/compact_index_client/updater.rb:51:in `block in update'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
  /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/compact_index_client/updater.rb:31:in `update'
...
```

I tried also to start the gemstash container with `--network host` in order to remove the network isolation but then even the `curl` command on my host is refused.

How can I have the service accessible from the `docker-compose build` command?

Answer (score 0):

Docker builds images in default bridge network by default. We can change that with `docker build  --network <network>`, but not with `docker-compose build`. Compose hasn't supported this yet. So, the only way to access `gemstash` container during the image build is starting it with `--network host` type and access it via host's IP address.

**1.** `docker-compose.yaml` is something like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  gemstash:
    image: <gemstash_image>
    network_mode: "host"

  rails_app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        IP_ADDRESS: ${IP_ADDRESS}
```

**2.** After `gemstash` container is started:

```
docker-compose up -d gemstash
```

we see that it is reachable on host's IP:

```
netstat -nlpt | grep 9292
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9292            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

**3.** Dockerfile is modified to:

```
ARG IP_ADDRESS
RUN bundle config mirror.https://rubygems.org http://$IP_ADDRESS:9292
```

where `IP_ADDRESS` is the host's IP address.

**4.** Inject `IP_ADDRESS` variable to `docker-compose.yaml`. For this we create `.env` file and define our variable there (example is for linux host):

```
IP_ADDRESS=$(ip a | grep <interface> | grep inet | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F'/' '{print $1}')
echo "IP_ADDRESS=$IP_ADDRESS" > .env
```

**5.** Now we can build `rails_app` and it could reach `gemstash` container:

```
docker-compose build
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice answer. Actually I have realised that the gem installed from a Github repo aren't covered by gemstash so I'm now looking at a solution like a Squid reverse caching proxy.